# Karma (AKA Testacular) rely on ng-app directive?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

After spending a day and a half of code battles, i've realized that the e2e tests hanged because i've bootstraped manually and not using ng-app directive

first, FYI.

second, any idea why? How can it be fixed?

thanks

Lior

--
EDIT: here're two plunks that show it, using phone-cat tutorial example:

works in both browser and e2e:
http://plnkr.co/edit/AfLsug1LRi0euKf7TWJa

works interactively in browser, doesnt work in e2e runner:
http://plnkr.co/edit/20OeZ5eV2ZbzgS1qDYfr

Comment: Hi, can you provide more examples or possibly a jsFiddle/plnkr link? There isn't enough information right now to help - we need to see more of your app structure, how your bootstrap works etc.

Answer (score 4):

Scenario runner appears to need to get a hold of ng-app (for the $injector). I adapted [the fix identified here by Vojta Jína](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/yslVnZh9Yjk/MLi3VGXZLeMJ) and it worked for me.

```
$(function() {
   var myApp = $('#appId'); // Use whatever selector is appropriate here. 
   angular.bootstrap(myApp, [modules]); // modules is optional - see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap
   myApp.addClass('ng-app'); // Adds the required ng-app
});
```

In addition, you may need to put a `pause` or `wait` in your `beforeAll` to allow enough time for manual bootstrapping to complete, e.g.,

```
beforeEach(function() {
   browser().navigateTo('../../index.html');
   pause();
});
```

This fix works but it's not that satisfactory imho. Is there any way to get rid of the pause/wait?

Comment: Any update on this answer; is there a better way to approach this? Or should the answer be marked as correct?