# Is it possible to run angularJS e2e tests using Karma and RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner

The documentation leads me to belive that this is not possible since AngularJS apps that use RequireJS are bootstrapped manually i.e.

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

Instead of using automatic bootstrapping via `ng-app` directive in html file. Still I think that there must be a way to make it work and if so perhaps there are some examples of using RequireJS with Karma and end to end tests? Can someone confirm or deny my conclusion. AngularJS and RequireJS e2e (integration) tests are not possible.

Comment: It is possible, but seems to require a wait/pause. I posted an [answer to a related question that might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557447/karma-aka-testacular-rely-on-ng-app-directive/16524459#16524459)

Comment: I ran into this just today it seems we have to add ng-app manually before bootstrapping that should od it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/yslVnZh9Yjk/MLi3VGXZLeMJ

Comment: yup, that was what worked for me (a link to that thread was also in my answer)